# character position in string

Tags: string, r, perl

I have a data frame with character strings in `column1` and ID in `column2`. The string contains `A,T,G or C`.
I would like to print the lines that have an `A` at position 1. 
Then I would like to print the lines that have `A` at position 2 and so on and save them in separate files.
So far I have used biostrings in R for similar analysis, but it won't work for this problem exactly. I would like to use perl.

```
Sequence                ID
TATACAAGGGCAAGCTCTCTGT  mmu-miR-381-3p
TCGGATCCGTCTGAGCT       mmu-miR-127-3p
ATAGTAGACCGTATAGCGTACG  mmu-miR-411-5p
......
600 more lines
```

Comment: Well the first run would be   `data[,1][order(substring(data[,1], 1, 1))]`.  So you should be able to iterate through the letters of each string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Biostrings will work perfectly, and will be pretty fast. Let's call your DNA stringset `mydata`

```
HasA <- sapply(mydata,function(x) as.character(x[2]) == "A")
```

Now you have a vector of TRUE or FALSE indicating which sequence has an A at position 2. You can make that into a nice data frame like this

```
HasA.df <- data.frame("SeqName" = names(mydata), "A_at_2" = HasA)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the expected result,

```
 mydata <- read.table(text="Sequence                ID
 TATACAAGGGCAAGCTCTCTGT  mmu-miR-381-3p
 TCGGATCCGTCTGAGCT       mmu-miR-127-3p
 ATAGTAGACCGTATAGCGTACG  mmu-miR-411-5p",sep="",header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)

  mCh <- max(nchar(mydata[,1])) #gives the maximum number of characters in the first column

 sapply(seq(mCh), function(i) substr(mydata[,1],i,i)=="A") #gives the index
```

You can use `which` to get the index of the row that satisfies the condition for each position

```
  res <-  stack(setNames(sapply(seq(mCh), 
        function(i) which(substr(mydata[,1],i,i)=="A")),1:mCh))[,2:1]

  tail(res, 5) #for the 13th position, 1st and 3rd row of the sequence are TRUE
  ind values
#11  13      1
#12  13      3
#13  14      2
#14  15      3
#15  20      3
```

use the index `values` to extract the rows.  For the 1st position

```
 mydata[res$values[res$ind==1],]
  #               Sequence             ID
# 3 ATAGTAGACCGTATAGCGTACG mmu-miR-411-5p
```

Comment: How do you print the lines from the original input matrix that are TRUE for each position?

Answer (score 0):

Using a perl one-liner

```
perl -Mautodie -lane '
  BEGIN {($f) = @ARGV}
  next if $. == 1;
  my @c = split //, $F[0];
  for my $i (grep {$c[$_] eq "A"} (0..$#c)) {
    open my $fh, ">>", "$f.$i";
    print $fh $_;
  }
' file
```